# Restart Policy on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker Containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a multi container Elastic Beanstalk application that contain 4 types of containers. One of the containers is `scrapinghub/splash` which is designed in a way that you can set a max memory limit where the container should shut down, and then the idea is that you run it with a `restart: always` policy that brings it up again.

From what I can see in the `Dockerrun.aws.json` syntax there is nothing like the normal docker-compose restart policy to define. From what I've found on other resources the recommended way is to create an ECS Service that restart the task whenever it fails.

However -- note that I don't want to restart my whole task that include all the containers, I only want to restart one of the containers. If I restart the whole task then all other worker-processes will stop running.

So how do I do this? How do I make sure that as soon as a container is shut down, it restarts again -- without restarting or redeploying the whole task? Just like the normal docker-compose restart policy setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the docs here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

Is stated the following:

If a Docker container running in an Elastic Beanstalk environment **crashes** or is killed for any reason, Elastic Beanstalk restarts it automatically.

So If I understand it correctly the restart policy is set to always by default

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to stop the docker daemon ( systemctl stop docker).
After that, I was able to stop the running container from the beanstalk env.